# Input string was not in a correct format in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, telerik

I know this is duplicate question. I have try finding the solution in duplicate question but I failed.

The situation is I have 2 combo box (Telerik Winforms) called ComboBranch and ComboPanel. ComboPanel will show different value when user select the some value in ComboBranch.

So this is the code

```
 private void tbDropBranch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.Data.PositionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataPanel();
    }

    void dataPanel()
    {

        DataTable dtPanel = dataBinding._valuePanel(Convert.ToInt32(tbDropBranch.SelectedValue.ToString())); // Error in here
        tbDropPanel.DataSource = new BindingSource(dtPanel, null);
        tbDropPanel.DisplayMember = "panelName";
        tbDropPanel.ValueMember = "panelID";

    }
```

**UPDATE**

If I do Event tbDropBranch_Leave it`s work. But why I got error when I use tbDropBranch_SelectedIndexChanged ?

```
 private void tbDropBranch_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dataPanel();

        }
```

**SOLUTION**

I just do like this :

```
void getIdBranch()
    {

        if ("System.Data.DataRowView" == tbDropBranch.SelectedValue.ToString())
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {

            DataTable dtPanel = dataBinding._valuePanel(Convert.ToInt32(tbDropBranch.SelectedValue.ToString()));
            tbDropPanel.DataSource = new BindingSource(dtPanel, null);
            tbDropPanel.DisplayMember = "panelName";
            tbDropPanel.ValueMember = "panelID";
        }

    }
```

Thank to those who helped.. :)

Comment: What is the value of `tbDropBranch.SelectedValue.ToString()`?

Comment: And what exactly is `dataBinding._valuePanel` ?

Comment: @JonB -  It will give branchID value. If I create event tbDropBranch_leave, Everything is ok. But event tbDropBranch_SelectedIndexChanged I got that error

Comment: do you have null value there or string.Empty value..?

Comment: @FrancisP : It contains the panel below each branch id.

Comment: when debugging what is the value..?

Comment: @Chuki2 Can you please provide the following information?

- The value of tbDropBranch whether it is a number or (a string that can NOT be converted to a number [e.g ABC])

Comment: But what is the value when this runs? It may be an empty string or some other unexpected value.

Comment: @DJKRAZE : It show System.Data.DataRowView.

Comment: @Chuki2 System.Data.DataRowView is not a valid string that can be parsed to Int. Are you sure that this is the value of the ComboBox? Can you please insert the following code before the line you are encountering errors with and tell me the output?: `MessageBox.Show(tbDropBranch.SelectedValue.ToString());`

Comment: @PicrofoEGY I think, when I execute. tbDropBranch_SelectedIndexChanged will continue to implement the code. That's why he came out System.Data.DataRowView. It`s same output

Comment: @Chuki2 Thanks for providing the information, I'm researching the problem.

Comment: @PicrofoEGY : Thanks for help mate. I have update on the question.

Comment: @Chuki2 I see that you have used TWO different voids in every event, You've used getIdBranch(); under Leave but used dataPanel(); under SelectedIndexChanged. Maybe because you are using TWO different voids the problem occurs?

Comment: @PicrofoEGY : I have make correction. I also have tried use dataPanel() under Leave. It`s ok. But Under SelectedIndexChanged, it`s error.

Comment: @Chuki2 That's confusing, I think that when the user changes the index there's no output but when the user leaves the object, there's an output. It might be a problem with the object itself as far as I think. Sorry about that

Comment: No problem, at least you try to help. Thanks mate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are receiving an exception because `tbDropBranch.SelectedValue.ToString()` can not be converted into an `Integer` or `Int`. I'd recommend you to insert the following line first to make sure if the string can be parsed before executing to avoid receiving exceptions. It'll be also appreciated if you could provide the exact exception you are receiving.

```
   int x = 0;
   void dataPanel()
    {
        if (Int32.TryParse(tbDropBranch.SelectedValue.ToString(), out x)) //Check if tbDropBranch.SelectedValue.ToString() is a valid integer
        {
          DataTable dtPanel = dataBinding._valuePanel(Convert.ToInt32(tbDropBranch.SelectedValue.ToString())); // Error in here
          tbDropPanel.DataSource = new BindingSource(dtPanel, null);
          tbDropPanel.DisplayMember = "panelName";
          tbDropPanel.ValueMember = "panelID";
        }
    }
```

You can always try the following to get the exact value of the current selected item based on its index

```
if (ComboBranch.SelectedIndex != -1) // Execute the following only if there's a selected index
   {
        ComboBranch.Items[ComboBranch.SelectedIndex].ToString(); // Get the value of the selected index
   }
```

Thanks

 I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: Nice man.. Your idea same with me. But my idea is `if ("System.Data.DataRowView" == tbDropBranch.SelectedValue.ToString()){return;}`. Hehe

Comment: @Chuki2 I'm glad you've found an answer to your question. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because `tbDropBranch.SelectedValue.ToString()` returns `System.Data.DataRowView`. `Convert.ToInt32` can't turn that value into an int. You'll need to pass in something else.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt `dataBinding._valuePanel` uses an `Int32` as its parameter... maybe it should be an `int`?

```
dataBinding._valuePanel(int.Parse(tbDropBranch.SelectedValue.ToString()));
```